# PHP Try Catch Buffer

Tags: php, linode

I was working on this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232498) and I found an unexpected situation.

When working in a PHP/HTML hybrid file, the book says, if I use PHP try/catch without the ob buffer thing, and if there's an error somewhere in the middle of the file, ***the PHP engine won't be able to reach the catch{} line since some output has already been sent to the browser***. The book then says this situation could be fixed by using ***ob_start(), ob_end_clean() and ob_end_flush()***

However, when I was playing with the book's sample code, the try/catch worked just fine ***without*** the ob buffer stuff. By saying just fine I mean if there's an exception the catch{} line could be reached and executed without a problem.

I used a Linode VPS for testing, the PHP version is 5.3.2. I set up the VPS with some ordinary Linode script.

Why is that? :)

Comment: That statement doesn't make a lot of sense to me...

Comment: done believe everything you read.

Comment: I would carefully re-read what it says, including all the relevant context that came before the statement. I doubt a published book would say something so wrong, so it's likely your interpretation.

Comment: @chris You must not have read a lot of published books... ;-P

Comment: @deceze, actually, no, I haven't lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That statement is nonsense. PHP's `try..catch` works just as you would expect, regardless of output that has or hasn't already been sent to the browser.

Seeing that even the [errata to that book](http://foundationphp.com/phpsolutions/updates.php) contains errors, I'd say it's simply not a very good book and am not surprised at all that it contains wrong statements. Just a very quick glance reveals:

> In step 4, the third line of code should read as follows:
>
> ```
> if ($_POST && isset($missing) && !empty($missing)) {
> ```

No, it should actually read:

```
if ($_POST && !empty($missing)) {
```

or

```
if ($_POST && $missing) {
```

The author apparently does not understand [how to use `empty`](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Further:

> An opening curly brace is missing at the end of line 4 of the code in step 2. It should read:
>
> ```
> if (!@include('includes/connection.inc.php')) {
> ```

That reeks of bad practices and should be rewritten to:

```
if (!file_exists('includes/connection.inc.php')) {
```

or:

```
require_once 'includes/connection.inc.php';
```

I'm sure there's more... :)

Comment: (To be fair, that's the errata to the first edition from 2006. I cannot say whether the errata errors are fixed in the second edition. Looking at some of the comments on Amazon though, there still seem to be problems...)